# High autocorrelation in GAMM

Tags: multilevel-analysis, autocorrelation, autoregressive, generalized-additive-model, gamm4

I am fitting a GAMM model to understand the evolution of fire elevation in time. I am using the mgcv package from R. My dataset contains 820 fires events with its corresponding elevation, time of occurrence (year) and the region it belongs to.

For the model, I set the elevation of fires as the response variable, time as the predictor and random smooths for each mountain regions.

```r
model <- gam(elevation ~ s(year) + 
              s(year, mt_region, bs = "fs", m = 1), data = fire_data, 
              method = "REML")
```

The summary of the model shows this:

```r
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
elevation ~ s(year) + s(year, mt_region, bs = "fs", m = 1)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1539.75      83.49   18.44   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                   edf Ref.df      F p-value    
s(year)          7.587  8.086  2.281  0.0102 *  
s(year,mt_region) 40.305 69.000 12.413  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.541   Deviance explained = 56.7%
-REML =   5829  Scale est. = 74754     n = 820
```

I have found high autocorrelation of residuals when plotting the ACF.

[image]

I added an autocorrelation structure with AR1 in the previous GAMM model.

```r
model2 <- gamm(elevation~ s(year) + 
           s(year, mt_region, bs = "fs", m =1), 
           data = fire_data, method = "REML", 
           correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1|year))
```

However, the residuals of the second model have similar high autocorrelation and I get an almost identical ACF plot. Is there something I'm doing wrong here and how can I solve this issue? Is the correlation structure correctly specified?

Comment: Did you extract and plot the *normalized* residuals? (Using `resid(model2, type = "normalized")`?)

Comment: I tried to extract the residuals as you suggested. However it seems that the normalized type does not exist for the resid function. R tells me that the only accepted types are: "deviance", "pearson","scaled.pearson", "working", or "response". I have noticed that when looking at the residuals of the models's lme component, autocorrelation had decreased.

Comment: In this instance you need to run `resid(model2$lme, type = "normalized")` and the relevant help file is `?nlme::residuals.lme`, not `?mgcv::residuals.gam`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your suggestion works. Is there a reason why we evaluate the normalized residuals of the lme call? Adding the autoregressive model successfully mitigated autocorrelation in the normalized lme residuals, but led to a slight increase of the gam's residuals autocorrelation (called as `resid(model2$gam)`). Which residuals should I care about when evaluation autocorrelation?

Answer (score 1):

Does this [itsadug-based approach](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/itsadug/vignettes/acf.html) using `bam` substantially reduce the autocorrelation?

```
# determine rho from the initial model
year_max <- max(fire_data$year) # or the last year
rho <- acf(resid(model), lag.max= year_max, plot=TRUE)$acf[2]

library(itsadug)
fire_data <- as.data.frame(fire_data)
fire_data <- start_event(fire_data, column="year", event=c("mt_region"), label.event="Event")

# new model with acf
new_model <- bam(elevation~ s(year) + s(year, mt_region, bs = "fs", m =1),
                  rho=rho, AR.start=fire_data$start.event,
                  data = fire_data, method = "REML")
acf(resid(new_model), lag.max= year_max, plot=TRUE)$acf[2]
 
# retrieve the corrected residuals of the model using resid_gam:
par(mfrow=c(1,2), cex=1.1)
# normal residuals:
normal.res <- resid(new_model)
acf(normal.res, lag.max=year_max)
# corrected residuals:
corrected.res <- resid_gam(new_model)
acf(corrected.res, lag.max=year_max)
```

Comment: `gamm()` doesn't have those arguments (`rho`, `AR.start`)